# List Comprehension - Select Columns based on a Variable

Tags: python, string, filter, dataframe, list-comprehension

My data frame is a compilation of ELA and Math columns. I ultimately want to drop one of the subjects' set of columns as I allow user input to choose one subject.

I'm trying to use a list comprehension to assign the dataframe any columns that have the subject name that is selected. The one nuance is that there are two columns that should be constant in both ELA and Math selections, 'Proficiency Category Math' and 'Proficiency Category ELA'.

Thoughts on how to use list comprehensions to accomplish this?

Input:

```
    ELA Score  Math Score  ELA Goal   Math Goal   Proficiency ELA  Proficiency Math
        1          4          6           7              3                 5
```

Output:(with subject_selection = 'Math')

```
    Math Score   Math Goal   Proficiency ELA   Proficiency Math
        4            7             3                   5
```

My current code:

```
    col_list = df.columns
    subject_selection = 'Math'   ###User types in desired subject
    x = df['Proficiency Category Math']
    y = df['Proficiency Category ELA']
    df = [cols for cols in col_list if subject_selection in cols or cols == x or cols == y]
```

The error I receive is:

```
    TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Comment: you are comparing a a column name with a value (which is int) in the row.

Comment: if you print `col_list` what does it look like? (Do any of the entries include the string 'Math' in them?)

Comment: @jcfollower col_list is supposed to be a list of the column names in my dataframe. I'm wondering if my issue is that I'm using list comprehension to filter out a series object?

Comment: Your list comprehension looks ok to me as long as `col_list` looks something like this ... 
`["ELA Score",  "Math Score",  "ELA Goal",   "Math Goal",   "Proficiency ELA",  "Proficiency Math"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare the *name* of the column to the *name* of the columns that you want to include, like you did for `subject_selection`.  In other words, you did `subject_selection = 'Math'`, not `subject_selection = df[['Math Score', 'Math Goal']]`.  Likewise, you should do:

```
x = 'Proficiency Category Math'
y = 'Proficiency Category ELA'
```

Comment: Ok! I realize that major issue. After I fixed that, I'm not getting my desired result. I'm getting a list returned of just my x and y variables. Is there something wrong with my list comprehension?@BrenBarn

Comment: @krisko08: You'll need to provide a self-contained, reproducible example demonstrating the problem.